# Problemas para recortar bakcground image

Tags: html, jquery, css

**Pagina.html**

```
<div id='resultado'></div>
       <img id="imagen1" src="http://img2.rtve.es/v/1451521/" '="" style="margin: 0px 576px 324px 0px;">
<div id='imagen'>Imagen</div>
```

**app.js**

```
    var margin_top= $('#imagen1').css('margin-top');
    var margin_right= $('#imagen1').css('margin-right');
    var margin_bottom= $('#imagen1').css('margin-bottom');
    var margin_left= $('#imagen1').css('margin-left'); 
    $('#imagen').css({
        'background-image':'url(http://img2.rtve.es/v/1451521/)' , 'margin-top' : margin_top+'px','margin-right' : margin_right+'px','margin-bottom' : margin_bottom+'px','margin-left' : margin_top+'px'
    });
```

Tengo varias imágenes en el código `html` con la misma url pero con diferentes recortes (`margin`). Las recorro con botones `next` y `previous` y quiero que se muestren en el `<div id="imagen">` pero no sé como utilizar la propiedad `background-image` con `margin`.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que quieres hacer pero con `margin` solo vas a separar el `div` del resto de elementos. ¿Podrías poner una imagen de lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, podrias aclararla un poco? hay un error o aparece algo diferente a lo que esperas?
por lo pronto tienes esto `'=""` en la img

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien, hay varias cosas mal en tu código, comenzando porque esta mal escrito, en la imagen esta resultando el código así:

```
<img id="imagen1" src="http://img2.rtve.es/v/1451521/" '=""> style="margin: 0px 576px 324px 0px;">
```

Y debería ser:

```
<img id="imagen1" src="http://img2.rtve.es/v/1451521/" style="margin: 0px 576px 324px 0px;">
```

Y no se porque quieres usar `margin`, esta propiedad sirve para generar espacios entre un elemento y otro, no para posicionar objetos.

Yo te recomiendo 2 opciones:

- **Opción 1:** `Position: Absolute; Top; Left; Right; y Bottom;`
- **Opción 2:** `Background-image:; Background-size; y Background-position;`

### Opción 1

Cuando la imagen debe estar en el html mediante una etiqueta `<img>`, si quieres solo mostrar un fragmento, deberás encerrarla en otra etiqueta que sirva de contenedor, por ejemplo un `<figure>`, aunque tu puedes usar `<div>` si quieres.

Algo así:

```
<figure id="contenedor-imagen" style="
   position: relative; 
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0;">
    <img src="http://picsum.photos/600/400/?image=1044" style="
         position: absolute;
         top: -100px;
         left: 0;" />
</figure>
```

Como puedes ver, **al contenedor** le estableces su posición como relativa, ayudando de eje a la imagen que contiene. Es necesario también la propiedad de `overflow: hidden;` que ocultará todo lo que sobresale del cuadro contenedor.

De segundo a la **etiqueta imagen** le añades la posición absoluta, esto permite situarlo con respecto al contenedor padre usando las propiedades `top, left, right y button`.

No es necesario que coloques todo el código css en linea, sería bueno poder aprovechar clases css pre-hechas que te funcionen como necesites y en js solo cambiar la posición de cada imagen, algo así:

```css
.contenedor-imagen{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}

.contenedor-imagen .imagen{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<figure class="contenedor-imagen">
  <img id="recorte01" class="imagen" src="http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044" style="top: 0; left: 0">
</figure>
<figure class="contenedor-imagen">
  <img id="recorte02" class="imagen" src="http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044" style="top: -20px; left: -200px">
</figure>
<figure class="contenedor-imagen">
  <img id="recorte03" class="imagen" src="http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044" style="bottom: -50px; left: -250px">
</figure>
<figure class="contenedor-imagen">
  <img id="recorte04" class="imagen" src="http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044" style="bottom: -50px; right: -100px">
</figure>
```

### Opción 2

La opción con `background-image`, que es la que creo quieres usar, tienes que combinarla con una etiqueta `<figure>`, `<div>` o la que quieras, en teoría la podrías usar con una etiqueta `<img>` vacía, pero eso acarrearía otros problemas, ya que esta sirve para llamar la imagen en el `html` directamente mediante el atributo `src` y lo que buscas con la propiedad background-image es que la imagen no esté en el html, sino que este llamada en el css y funcione como fondo de una etiqueta.

Para usarla, basta con combinar las propiedades:

- **background-image:** url('/img/imagen.jpg');
- **background-size:** width height ;
- **background-position:** posiciónX posctiónY;

Es importante precisar que por defecto, `background-size:;` esta en automatico, es decir: `background-size: auto;` y esto significa que traerá la imagen con el tamaño por defecto de esta, ahora si quieres tener un mayor control, sería bueno que delimiten su tamaño a un estándar.

Un ejemplo sería así:

```
<figure id="contenedor-imagen" style="
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   background-image: url('/img/imagen.jpg');
   background-size: 800px 600px;
   background-position: 0 -200px;
">
<figure id="contenedor-imagen02" style="
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   background-image: url('/img/imagen.jpg');
   background-size: 800px 600px;
   background-position: -100px -400px;
">
```

Aunque es mejor si lo combinas con css, como con el ejemplo anterior, el código quedaría más limpio sin repetir tanto código.

En el **`CSS`** sería:

```
.imagen-recortada{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   background-size: 800px 600px;  
}
```

Y en el **`HTML`** sería

```
<figure id="imagen01" class="imagen-recortada" style="background-position: 0 -200px; background-image: url('/img/imagen01.jpg');">
<figure id="imagen02" class="imagen-recortada" style="background-position: -100px -400px; background-image: url('/img/imagen02.jpg');">
```

Aquí un ejemplo en vivo:

```css
.imagen-recortada{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   margin: 0;
   background-size: 800px 600px;  
}
```

```html
<figure id="imagen01" class="imagen-recortada" style="
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044');
"></figure>

<figure id="imagen02" class="imagen-recortada" style="
   background-position: -100px -400px;
   background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044');
"></figure>

<figure id="imagen03" class="imagen-recortada" style="
   background-position: -600px 0px;
   background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044');
"></figure>

<figure id="imagen04" class="imagen-recortada" style="
   background-position: -300px 100%;
   background-image: url('http://picsum.photos/800/600/?image=1044');
"></figure>
```

Cualquier duda, no olvides usar la caja de comentarios.